# Reading in a binary file in C, then matching data from the file to what I have read in

Tags: c, binaryfiles

So I'm trying to read in a binary file with 4 bytes per chunk, and when doing a hexdump on my file here is the output: 

`0000000 0022 0000 6261 6463 3030 3030 6261 6463
0000010 3030 3030 6261 6463 3030 3030 6261 6463
*
00000d0 3030 3030 6261 6463 3030 3030 000a
00000dd`

(There shouldn't be a line in between each line of digits, sorry)

But when it reads these values into an array here is the output I'm getting:

`34 61000000 30646362 61303030 30646362 61303030 30646362 61303030 30646362 2283030 0 44c5bbc0 7fff 22 0 14fea515 7f68 0 0 22 0 22 0 4007b2 0 1 0 1000 0 2289010 0 44c5bbc0 7f`

I've followed a lot of instructions online and I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned char buffer[1];
    FILE *filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    //unsigned char buffer[filePointer];

    int readVal = 0;

    readVal = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, filePointer);
    if (readVal == 0)
    {
            printf("File did not read anything\n");
    }

    int size = buffer[0];

    /*int i = 1;    

    for(; i < 1; i++)
    {
            printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
    }

    */
    //int size = buffer[0];
    printf("%d\n", size);
    unsigned int array[size];
    int otherDataElements;

    otherDataElements = fread(array, sizeof(buffer), size, filePointer);

    if (otherDataElements == 0)
    {
            printf("There was nothing there!");
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (; j < size; j++)
    {
            printf("%x ", array[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is some code commented out, ignore it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is `size`? Number of bytes? or integers?

This seems suspicious:

```
otherDataElements = fread(array, sizeof(buffer), size, filePointer);
```

Try changing to this:

```
otherDataElements = fread(array, sizeof(unsigned int), size/sizeof(unsigned int), filePointer);
```

Because array is `array` of unsigned integers and second parameter to `fread` asks you for size of each element to be read. File length should also be multiple of 4 if you want to interpret the file contents as array of 4 byte integers I think.

Anyway the output of this program on my machine is (this is similar program as yours just added writing data to file for testing - and I have simplified reading):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    unsigned char buffer[1];
    FILE *filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("/Users/macbookair/Documents/test/test/t.bin", "rb");

    //unsigned char buffer[filePointer];


    //readVal = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, filePointer);
    //if (readVal == 0)
    //{
    //     printf("File did not read anything\n");
    // }

    //int size = 4;

    /*int i = 1;

     for(; i < 1; i++)
     {
     printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
     }

     */
    //int size = buffer[0];
    //printf("%d\n", size);
    unsigned int array[4] = {0};
    int otherDataElements;
    int nrOfInts = 1; // In this test method we only want to read 1 integer from file, we assume there is one integer only

    otherDataElements = fread(array, sizeof(unsigned int), nrOfInts, filePointer);

    if (otherDataElements == 0)
    {
        printf("There was nothing there!");
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (; j < nrOfInts; j++)
    {
        printf("%x ", array[j]);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Just do a test write to file. Write 4 bytes to read back later.
    FILE *write_ptr;
    unsigned char buffer[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    write_ptr = fopen("/Users/macbookair/Documents/test/test/t.bin","wb");   

    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,write_ptr);  
    fclose(write_ptr);

    // Call our method for reading the data
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

this:

```
3020100
```

You can see the output is swapped but that is because of endianness - when my computer interpreted bytes 00 01 02 03 as bytes of an integer, it did so in little endian way - hence the output is integer 03020100. You may want to consider this also in your case. So in my case it worked fine I guess.